# jq print value of an element where a key array is empty or a key is missing

Tags: json, jq

```
{
    "vehicle": [
        {
            "type": "car",
            "features": [
                {
                    "airbags": "yes",
                    "engine": [
                        {
                            "electric": "yes",
                            "horsepower": "1000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "number": "ABCD 1234"
                }
            ],
            "price": "100000"
        },
        {
            "type": "truck",
            "features": [],
            "price": "500000"
        },
        {
            "type": "train",
            "features": [
                {
                    "airbags": "no",
                    "engine": [
                        {
                            "horsepower": "10000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "number": "MNOPQRST"
                }
            ],
            "price": "100000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `jq` or `jmespath`, I want value of `type` where `vehicle[].features[]` is either an empty array or it is missing `vehicle[].features[].engine[].electric` element.

So this json should list me `truck` and `train` as truck is has an empty array `vehicle[].features[]` and train is missing `vehicle[].features[].engine[].electric` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your particular input where it seems `features` and `engines` have always at most one element, you should be able to do:

```
jq -r '.vehicle[] | select(.features[0].engine[0].electric != "yes").type'
```

Or:

```
jq -r '.vehicle[] | select(.features[0].engine[0] | has("electric") | not).type'
```

for the `type` of those `vehicle`s whose first `engine` of the first `features` has `not` got an `electric` key.

Or if like me you know `perl` or another programming language already and would rather not learn yet another (and very specific) one like `jq`s:

```
perl -MJSON -l -0777 -ne '
  $j = from_json($_);
  for (@{$j->{vehicle}}) {
    print $_->{type} unless $_->{features}[0]->{engine}[0]->{electric} eq "yes"
  }' < file.js
```

(or `unless defined($_->{features}[0]->{engine}[0]->{electric})`).

Comment: There's a problem, this example of json has yes and no but it was a bit simplified, actually, there is an IP address at that place and it can have n number of possibilities. So, any solution around checking if there is an IP address or not?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, see edit.

Comment: Love you, might be a bit cheeky, but thanks a lot..